# if image url contains character like "+" can't save image

Tags: php, file-get-contents, scrape

I'm trying to save images when an user posts an image url.
I'm doing this with this code:

```
        $pic = $Db->escape($_POST['form_pic']); // (escape is a function to mysql_real_escape_string)
        $time = strtotime("now");
        $filename = $item_id.'_'.$time.'.'.$ext;
        $item_pic = 'img/ads/'.$filename;

        $contents = file_get_contents($pic);
        file_put_contents('../img/ads/'. $filename, $contents);
```

This works in most of the cases. But when the url contains a strange character like a "+", then the above code isn't working. He doesn't save the image then.

```
 An example url: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ubBMWObG6u0/T-m3zYIq3CI/AAAAAAAABxU/Z8aa1Dgny9c/s1600/Grown+sunglasses.jpg
```

How can I save every image file, even if the url contains "strange" characters?

**Update:** I've echoed my $_POST['form_pic'] and it seems like that when I post the url after submit that the "+" character is replaced by a space?

Comment: Why are you MySQL-escaping a URL and then requesting it? Doesn't the escaping change the whole URL? Try printing `$pic` to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: removed the mysql escaping. still doesn't work. Is there something strange about the url?

Comment: The + could be an encoded space.  Perhaps a urldecode() will help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Use this,

```
$pic = str_replace("+","_",$pic);
```